# How to count lines of code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried `rake stats` but that seems highly inaccurate. Perhaps it ignores several directories?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try out these two options:

1. [Hack rake stats](http://www.pervasivecode.com/blog/2007/06/28/hacking-rakestats-to-get-gross-loc/)

Rakestats snippet from blogpost:

```
namespace :spec do
  desc "Add files that DHH doesn't consider to be 'code' to stats"
  task :statsetup do
  require 'code_statistics'

  class CodeStatistics
    alias calculate_statistics_orig calculate_statistics
    def calculate_statistics
      @pairs.inject({}) do |stats, pair|
        if 3 == pair.size
          stats[pair.first] = calculate_directory_statistics(pair[1], pair[2]); stats
        else
          stats[pair.first] = calculate_directory_statistics(pair.last); stats
        end
      end
    end
  end
  ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << ['Views',  'app/views', /\.(rhtml|erb|rb)$/]
  ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << ['Test Fixtures',  'test/fixtures', /\.yml$/]
  ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << ['Email Fixtures',  'test/fixtures', /\.txt$/]
  # note, I renamed all my rails-generated email fixtures to add .txt
  ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << ['Static HTML', 'public', /\.html$/]
  ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << ['Static CSS',  'public', /\.css$/]
  # ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << ['Static JS',  'public', /\.js$/]
  # prototype is ~5384 LOC all by itself - very hard to filter out

  ::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "Test Fixtures"
  ::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "Email Fixtures"
  end
end
task :stats => "spec:statsetup"
```

2. [metric_fu](https://github.com/metricfu/metric_fu/) - A Ruby Gem for Easy Metric Report Generation

PS: I haven't tried any of the above, but metric_fu sounds interesting, see the screenshots of the output.

Answer (score 112):

I use the free Perl script [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net). Sample usage:

```
phrogz$ cloc .
     180 text files.
     180 unique files.                                          
      77 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.56  T=1.0 s (104.0 files/s, 19619.0 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Javascript                      29           1774           1338          10456
Ruby                            61            577            185           4055
CSS                             10            118            133            783
HTML                             1             13              3            140
DOS Batch                        2              6              0             19
Bourne Shell                     1              4              0             15
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                           104           2492           1659          15468
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: it seems that it does not support `erb` view files. `cloc app/views`: 100 text files. 96 unique files. 100 files ignored. **Update: `cloc app/views --force-lang=html,erb`**

Comment: @Mifeng Thanks a lot! You can do the same with jade, which also isn't supported out of the box. eg. `cloc example/jadeviews --force-lang=html,jade`

Comment: `apt-get install cloc` for linux

Comment: It seems to support erb by now. Even haml works out of the box.

Answer (score 37):

Here's a simple solution. It counts the lines of code in your rails project's app folder - CSS, Ruby, CoffeeScript, and all. At the root of your project, run this command:

```
find ./app -type f | xargs cat | wc -l
```

EDIT

Read the comments. Then try this instead:

```
find ./app -type f -name "*.rb" | xargs cat | sed "/^\s*\(#\|$\)/d" | wc -l
```

Comment: and several orders of magnitude faster than cloc, if you don't care about the semantics of the lines you're counting

Comment: I'm really not sure why this got upvoted so much. It simply counts file lines, including blank lines and comments from any source code, configuration files, log files, binary files for crying out loud.That's **very** different from LOC, by any possible definition of what constitutes a line of code. On my current rails project, this reports 35K lines, vs. much more accurate 19K from cloc.

Comment: @Thilo, it actually doesn't count config or binary files because it's looking in ./app folder. Though fair enough, there's multiple solutions to everything.

Comment: @AminAriana All your assets (and hence images) are under `app/`, so while my comment was a bit too general, it wasn't by much. This will still be inaccurate enough to be meaningless, potentially by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Neat: Added this: " find ./app -type f -name \*.rb | xargs cat | wc -l " to just count ruby code

Comment: Added crop blank, spaced or commented out lines: `find ./app -type f -name *.rb | xargs cat | sed "/^\s*\(#\|$\)/d" | wc -l`

Comment: @Thilo:  I upvoted this because I do not have to install anything I don't already have to obtain a "close enough" answer for my needs.

Answer (score 14):

This one calculates number of files, total lines of code, comments, and average LOC per file. It also excludes files inside directories with "vendor" in their name.

Usage:

```
count_lines('rb')
```

Code:

```
def count_lines(ext)

  o = 0 # Number of files
  n = 0 # Number of lines of code
  m = 0 # Number of lines of comments

  files = Dir.glob('./**/*.' + ext)

  files.each do |f|
    next if f.index('vendor')
    next if FileTest.directory?(f)
    o += 1
    i = 0
    File.new(f).each_line do |line|
      if line.strip[0] == '#'
        m += 1
        next
      end
      i += 1
    end
    n += i
  end

  puts "#{o.to_s} files."
  puts "#{n.to_s} lines of code."
  puts "#{(n.to_f/o.to_f).round(2)} LOC/file."
  puts "#{m.to_s} lines of comments."

end
```

Comment: This is so simple, it's beaut'

Answer (score 0):

If your code is hosted on GitHub, you can use this line count website. Just enter your GitHub URL and wait for the result.

Example for Postgres: https://line-count.herokuapp.com/postgres/postgres

```
File Type   Files   Lines of Code   Total lines
Text        1336    0               472106
C           1325    1069379         1351222
Perl        182     23917           32443
Shell       5       355             533
...
```